# Accessing parent page with javascript inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, security, jsp, iframe, cross-domain

Is there any way to "break out" of an iframe? What I mean by this is that people will be placing my javascript tag inside an iframe (sometimes it ends up being nested iframes, but lets just deal with ONE for a now). I'm trying to gather certain information, like where that iframe is located on the page. It's easy enough to do it when you're not in an iframe with a mix of offsetLeft/offsetTop/innerHeight/innerWidth, but I know that you can't (or aren't supposed to be able) to see anything outside the iframe your in (assuming different domains, which it will be).

Anybody have any tips on this? Or at least any resources I could look into more? While I would eventually love to be able to access the DOM of the original page, with JS inside an iframe, I know that's not really possible. For a now I'd be happy to just figure out where the iframe is located on the page. I'm not sure if that information is part of the DOM, or browser properties (which I believe you can still access?)

Thanks!

Comment: If you want certain info (eg location) then you can make that a requirement for providing the content back to your clients. Just give them examples of how to call your content (supplying helper JS, etc). And your page can use the info or return error content to the caller.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately there's times when my tag will be passed between a number of people, added into other systems and spat out on the other side ect. so I'm not in the position to implement rules.

Can you access the URL of the page you end up on? Even if you're nested in one or more iframes? Or does that still go against the security policy...

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is that with CORS and cross frame/domain messaging you are now better off than previously. But you will get a fat "ACCESS DENIED" if you try to access the DOM in the parent frame from another domain.

If you put some javascript in the parent that can load stuff like images that set cookies on your server, then yes. but I guess that is not what you mean

Here is an example on how you can get the origin - have the users of your iframe load it like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script src="yourIframeLoader.php?parent='+escape(location.href)+'"><\/script>');
    </script>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid of. I'll looking into the cross frame/domain messaging a bit more now and see if that _might_ help me, but I doubt it. The greatest problem I have is that I'm completely out of control of what page I end up on. So there will be different domains, I can't add any extra JS to it to load images/cookies, nothing.

Can you at least see what domain you end up on? If you're in one or more iframes, can you access/see what page you're ultimately on?

Comment: If the parent domain owner is not adding extra scripts to his page, then you are AFAIK completely out of luck these days.
If you can make the person add some snippets then you can do stuff. See my answer for examples

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work cross-domain. It's a major security feature to keep javascript from working between domains (it's called the same-origin policy).

Imagine you start on some evil site: `www.evil.com`. From there, somehow, they trick you into clicking on a link that you expect to take you to a sensitive site (paypal, your bank, whatever). Instead of actually sending you to that site though, they actually iFrame it in. You go ahead and log in. BAM.

If their scripts had access to the cross-domain iFrame's DOM, they could easily snag any of the data that you're passing through the log in forms. Nasty, eh? There's just no way to deal with this safely, so it's shut off (except, arguably, JSONP)

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement some javascript functions on the parent page and call them from within the iframe by calling `parent.Myfunction();`

As for determining the position of the iframe, I'm not sure on that one.

Answer (score 0):

While an iFrame can't directly change its parent, the parent can read data from the iFrame.

This means that the parent HTML page can use JS to look at data in child iFrames.

If you control both the parent and the iFrame content, then you can set up message passing from the iFrame to the parent through an agreed element id in the iFrame.